# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :article_id=>nil, :id=>nil} for editing comments for article in ruby on rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

My app was working fine until I decided to add edit functionality for comments. Before it, I could view particular article but not now. Now I am getting routing error as `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :article_id=>nil, :id=>nil}` when I try to access particular article(articles/show) which has some comments.
Actually I was trying to implement comment editing functionality for article. For this,I have put "Edit" link for comments in comments/_comment.html.erb.It is noticeable that I do get this error only if article  has comments and when article does not have comments , it does not get.
I have separate views for articles and comments.

comments_controller.rb

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
         before_filter :user_signed_in, except: [:create]
        def new
          @comment = Comment.new
        end

        def create
          @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
          @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
          @comment.user_id = current_user.id
          @comment.save
            flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
            redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
        end

        def edit
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        end

        def update
         @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
         @article = @comment.article
         respond_to do |format|
          if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
            redirect_to @article_path(@article)
          else
           render :action => "edit" 
          end
        end

        def destroy
         @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
        @comment.destroy
           redirect_to @article_path(@artilce) 
        end

    end
```

comments/edit.html.erb

```
    <h3>Editing comment</h3>
    <%= render :partial => 'comment_form' %>
```

comments/_comment_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]), :required => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :article_id %> 
    <%= f.text_area :content, :style => "width:727px; height:100px; border: 1px solid #999999;margin-top:80px; background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-left:-33px" %>
        <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :style => "margin-right:20px; margin-left:560px; background-color:#66C9Ef; color:#FFFFFF; border: 0px solid #82b548; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; font-size: 1.3rem;" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

comments/comment.html.erb ( here i have given link for editing comments for an article)

```
    <% if @article.comments.count  >= 1 %>
      <div style="border: px solid #66c9ee;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;margin: 10px -30px 15px; padding:     10px 15px 25px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F2F2; width:700px; font-size: 1.2em;border-bottom: 0px solid #DDDDDD;">
          <%= comment.content %>
             <div id="tabula"> 
                <ul id="tabula">
                 <li> <div style="color: #0077CC;margin-rigth:200px; font-size: 1.0em;margin-top:4px;background-color:#;"> <%= comment.user.username if comment.user %></div></li>
                 <li> <div style="color: #0077CC; background-color:; margin-top:4px; margin-left:25px;"> <p> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at.in_time_zone("Asia/Calcutta"))  unless comment.created_at.nil? %>  </p></div></li>
                 <li> <div style="color: #0077CC; background-color:; margin-top:4px; margin-left:25px;"> <%= link_to "edit", edit_article_comment_path(@article,comment) %> </div></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
              </div>
        <% else %>
            <div style="color:#0077CC;margin-left:25px;font-size:1.4em;"> be first to comment</div>
      <% end %>
```

rake routes result.(not complete)

```
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
     dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)                              dashboard#index
                     POST   /dashboard(.:format)                              dashboard#create
       new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)                          dashboard#new
      edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)                     dashboard#edit
           dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#show
                     PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#update
                     DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#destroy


                   tags GET    /tags(.:format)                                   tags#index
                         POST   /tags(.:format)                                   tags#create
                 new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)                               tags#new
                edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)                          tags#edit
                     tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#show
                         PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#update
                         DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#destroy
        article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
     new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
    edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
         article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                         GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                         POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
                         GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
                         GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
                         GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                         PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
```

routes.rb

```
    Mau::Application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      root :to => 'articles#index'
      resources :articles
      resources :dashboard
      resources :tags
      resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
    end
```

comments_comment.html.erb

```
<% if @article.comments.count  >= 1 %>
  <div style="border: px solid #66c9ee;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;margin: 10px -30px 15px; padding:     10px 15px 25px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F2F2; width:700px; font-size: 1.2em;border-bottom: 0px solid #DDDDDD;">
      <%= comment.content %>
         <div id="tabula"> 
            <ul id="tabula">
             <li> <div style="color: #0077CC;margin-rigth:200px; font-size: 1.0em;margin-top:4px;background-color:#;"> <%= comment.user.username if comment.user %></div></li>
             <li> <div style="color: #0077CC; background-color:; margin-top:4px; margin-left:25px;"> <p> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at.in_time_zone("Asia/Calcutta"))  unless comment.created_at.nil? %>  </p></div></li>
             <li> <div style="color: #0077CC; background-color:; margin-top:4px; margin-left:25px;"> <%= link_to "edit", edit_article_comment_path(@article ,@comment) %> </div></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
    <% else %>
        <div style="color:#0077CC;margin-left:25px;font-size:1.4em;"> be first to comment</div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your article view and your _comment partial?

Comment: hi alexBrand, I have added _comment partia. Regarding article view, are you asking articles/show or index page. I have already added articles/show page.If you need more code to paste, please let me know.

Comment: can show us your rake routes result? probably there is wrong route path

Comment: hi Nich, I have already added rake routes result. Please check question.

Comment: hi, I do not get this error when I visit an article which does not have comments. I have added "Edit" link in comments/_comment.html.erb. Please have look there.

Comment: Do you have the comment form in the same page where you are displaying the comments? Can you show the article view?

Comment: hi alexBrand, after making changes in commemts/_comment.html.erb, I am able to view all the comments on an article and even "edit" link work somehow but not perfectly. problem is that when i click "Edit" link, it does not show any content in it. means after clicking "Edit" link , text area become empty. could you please look at comments_controller.rb( specially edit and update action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% if @article.comments.count  >= 1 %>
  <div "...">
    <%= comment.content %> # <-- This.
```

I am putting my suspicions on `<%= comment.content %>` and other `comment` variables found in *comments_comment.html.erb* and *comments/comment.html.erb*.

Seems plausible to me, since you don't receive errors if the article in question has no comments, as `@article.comments.count >= 1` returns `false`.

To have a working `comment` variable, insert a loop after the if statement:

```
<% if @article.comments.count  >= 1 %>
  <div "...">
    <% @article.comments.each do |comment| %> # <-- This.
      <%= comment.content %>
      ...
    <% end %> # Remember to close the loop.
  </div>
<% else %>
...
```

Also, take note to use `comment` instead of `@comment` in `edit_article_comment_path` in *comment/_comment.html.erb*.

Comment: even I sense that problem lies in partials of comments. But exactly I do not know. I have put "Edit" link comments/_comment.html.erb. is this look fine to you.

Comment: hi Sunxperous, but how does it show routing error, when edit action is in comments_controller.rb.

Comment: I have expanded my answer, do see if it solves the routing error issue. The error might have been caused by `edit_article_comment_path`.

Comment: hi Sunxperous, waw I worked for me. Now we can show all comments for an article and clicking on edit link shows edit form but problem is, when I click on edit link , it does not show content in it. I mean it shows us empty text area. but for editing purpose, like we can see on stakoverflow, when we edit our question, text box shows origin content in it. any suggestion, I think problem is in comments_controller.rb (with edit and update action.)

Comment: Replace `form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build])` with `form_for @comment` since `@comment` is the comment being retrieved in the edit action. There is no need to include `hidden_field :article_id`, since the article the comment belongs to is made known in the update action via `@article = @comment.article`. I may be wrong with regards to the article part though.

Comment: Hi Sunxperous, I think problem is in commments_controller.rb and with in edit and update action. because clicking on edit link does not carry its content. could you see any problem here.

Comment: Did you replace with `form_for @comment` yet? Also remove `:required => true`. Do update us with the new code if this still fails to work.

Comment: I have replaced it but still I am getting same error. looking at this issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28835/discussion-between-vsiingh-and-sunxperous)

Answer (score 0):

You are only showing the comments if the method #count returns 1 or greater. When you call the method count it count directly on the database, in the the case of an article without any comments, it will render nothing, so that's because you can see an article without comments.

But, when a comment exists, you are building a new comment to show up in the form and also trying to create a edit link for it.

So my solution is, change your form_for, since you dont need to resend all of your comments again, pass a new comment as parameter, instead of build one on the comments collection. Then on the other view, you can create a edit link for each of the persisted comments.

Comment: hi Paulo, thanks for your suggestion. do I need to change parameters in form_for or need to change form_for itself.Could you explain it bit.Thanks

Comment: Just change the line of form_for for this "<%= form_for ([@article, Comment.new]), :required => true do |f| %>"

Comment: hi Paulo Henrique, I tried with your suggestion but still I am getting error. No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :article_id=>#<Article id: 21, title: "good for health", body: "uby on Rails 3 Model Data Validation\r\nRails Model D...", created_at: "2013-04-14 15:14:19", updated_at: "2013-04-24 05:51:20", user_id: 1, impressions_count: 39>, :id=>nil}. It shows id is nil. is this creating problem.